# Is a theorem of a consistent and complete extension of L a tautology?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

If in a consistent and complete system we can deduce $A$, that is $⊢_J A$, what can be said about the valuation $V(A)$ or the truth value of $A$?

Comment: What is L ? And what is J ?

Comment: L is the logical system that is generally handled in books like Elliott Mendelson or Hamilton. On the other hand, J is a complete and consistent system, in which for any preposition we have that $A$ or $¬A$ is a theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If a formula $A$ is derivable from a set $J$ of axioms (i.e. it is a *theorem* of the theory having the said axioms), it is a [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) of the axioms, i.e. it is *true* in every interpretation satisfying the axioms.

It is not necessarily *valid* (i.e. true in every interpretation): the formula $1+1=2$ is provable from the axioms of arithmetic, but it is not valid.

And it is not necessarily a *tautology*: the formula $\forall x (x=x)$ is valid but it is not a tautology.